# NetMQ - TLS / SSL implementation for XPub / XSub pattern

Tags: netmq

I'm trying to implement TLS in XPub / XSub pattern example, the example was taken from https://netmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/xpub-xsub/

I tried to use NetMQCertificate for CURVE (https://github.com/zeromq/netmq/blob/master/src/NetMQ.Tests/CurveTests.cs)

I also tried to use NetMQ.Security (https://github.com/NetMQ/NetMQ.Security/blob/master/tests/NetMQ.Security.Tests/SecureChannelTests.cs)

Can someone pls help me with an example? or with a direction?